# Run through multiple dates Python

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I am trying to go back to March 29th 2018 and run through each day till today. Also save each day individually to .csv and change the name BOOKS_thedate.csv.
I have been meaning to apply datetime another way and any help understanding this would be much appreciated.

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

outfile = open("BOOKS.csv","w",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["book_ids","status","away_team_id","away_rot","ml_away","spread_away","spread_away_line","home_team_id",
                 "home_rot","ml_home","spread_home","spread_home_line","over","under","total","type_odds","insert","time",
                 "one_tm_id","one_tm","one_team","two_tm_id","two_tm","two_team"])

req2 = requests.get('https://api-prod.sprtactn.co/web/v1/scoreboard/mlb?bookIds=21,1,55&date=' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d') + '')
odd = req2.json()['games']

for info in odd:
    time = info['start_time']
    status = info['status']
    away_rot = info['away_rotation_number']
    home_rot = info['home_rotation_number']
    away_team_id = info['away_team_id']
    home_team_id = info['home_team_id']
    teams = info['teams']
    vegas = info['odds']
    one_team = teams[0]['full_name']
    one_tm = teams[0]['abbr']
    one_tm_id = teams[0]['id']
    two_team = teams[1]['full_name']
    two_tm = teams[1]['abbr']
    two_tm_id = teams[1]['id']
    for odds in vegas:
        ml_away = odds['ml_away']
        ml_home = odds['ml_home']
        type_odds = odds['type']
        insert = odds['inserted']
        book_ids = odds['book_id']
        spread_away = odds['spread_away']
        spread_home = odds['spread_home']
        spread_away_line = odds['spread_away_line']
        spread_home_line = odds['spread_home_line']
        over = odds['over']
        under = odds['under']
        total = odds['total']


        print(book_ids, status, away_team_id, away_rot, ml_away, spread_away, spread_away_line, 
              home_team_id, home_rot, ml_home, spread_home, spread_home_line,
              over, under, total, type_odds, insert, time, one_tm_id, one_tm, one_team, two_tm_id, two_tm, two_team)

        writer.writerow([book_ids, status, away_team_id, away_rot, ml_away, spread_away, spread_away_line, 
              home_team_id, home_rot, ml_home, spread_home, spread_home_line,
              over, under, total, type_odds, insert, time, one_tm_id, one_tm, one_team, two_tm_id, two_tm, two_team])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to use the Pendulum library (https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/).

Calculate the `start` and `end` times, then the `period` based on these. Execute a for-loop that provides one datetime item for each interval within the `period`, in this case for every day.

Within the loop you can format the datetime to provide a string for use in the URL and for naming the csv, as shown.

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> start = pendulum.datetime(2018, 3, 29)
>>> end = pendulum.today()
>>> period = pendulum.period(start, end)
>>> for dt in period.range('days'):
...     dt.format('%Y%m%d')
...     break
... 
'20180329'
```

Comment: What did you use to print the date like so. I made a string the_date = dt and it gives me `2018-03-29T00:00:00+00:00`

Comment: Printing the date in the way that you did makes `pendulum` print `dt` in its default format. If you want it formatted then use `dt.format(<format>)`. For instance, `print(dt.format('%Y%m%d'))` in the code above would have yielded `20180329` (ie, without the apostrophes).

Comment: `>>> import pendulum`
`>>> start = pendulum.datetime(2018, 3, 29)`
`>>> end = pendulum.today()`
`>>> period = pendulum.period(start, end)`
`>>> for dt in period.range('days'):`
 `dt.format('%Y%m%d')`
 `break`

'%2018%0%4'  This is what I receive after following it step by step..

Comment: Apologies! With version 2 the format function has changed, and I was using version 1. `dt.format('YYYYMMDD')` gives '20180329'.

Comment: There it is! I was using lower case m and d aswell which was printing the day. Thanks for the help Bill! Now I would pass the `period` `str` in the URL and put `the_date` `str` into the csv, right? Do I have to add in `outfile.close()` so it closes and moves to the next?

Comment: You should capture the result of `format` as, say, `result = dt.format('YYYYMMDD'` and then put `result` in the URL and in the name of the csv file. (I assume the date is to be formatted the same way in both.) Then, yes, close the csv file at the end of the loop to be opened afresh the next time around.